# how to fix into two decimal places - php

Tags: jquery

Hi I have following table

```
<table id="rates">
    <tr id="r1" class="edited">
        <td><input type="text" name="f11" value="10" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="f12" value="20" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="r2">
        <td><input type="text" name="f21" value="50" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="f22" value="60" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="r3" class="edited">
        <td><input type="text" name="f31" value="100" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="f32" value="200" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When input text change I add a class `.edited` to `tr`. What I want is, I want to fixed all the values in `.edited` row to two decimal places after any text change.  How can I achive that. Plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 jQuery('input').change(function(){
      var $row = jQuery('.edited');
        var values = $row.find("input:text").map(function() {
            return jQuery(this).val();
        }).get();


        $row.each(function() {
          jQuery(this).find("input:text").each(function(index) {
              var val = values[index];
              jQuery(this).val(Number(val).toFixed(2));
          });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

when you confirm the new edited value just apply `.toFixed()` method specifying how many digits you want after decimal point. This method is applied to a `number` value, so before using that method just do a `parseInt` of the value string

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me to find a answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$('input').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('edited');
    $('tr.edited input').each(function(){
       this.value = Math.round(this.value*100)/100;
    });
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/F5Ghx/

Comment: The fiddle doesnt seem to work for me on Chrome. 
Replace "Math.round(this.value*100)/100;" with 
"new Number(this.value).toFixed(2);"

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti You code is didn't work for me in firefox. I don't know why. I made a code by researching. I don't know it is the best answer but works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sara this works for me in firefox. Remember that the extra digits are added only if they are needed, so 100 will remain 100.